# Calling a self variable after it's value has been changed

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a variable declared in my init called self.current_color = (124, 124, 124)

Later on a function changes the tuple value of: (124, 124, 124) to (65, 76, 436) and I have a getter (get_cc) that returns current_color

How do I have it get the value AFTER it's been changed, it only returns the (124, 124, 124) not the (65, 74, 436)?

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's difficult to tell where the problem is, but what you're trying to achieve is pretty straight forward. Look at this small example:

```
In [1]: class MyClass:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.current_color = (124, 124, 124)
   ...:
   ...:     def change_color(self):
   ...:         self.current_color = (65, 76, 436)
   ...:
   ...:     def get_cc(self):
   ...:         return self.current_color
   ...:

In [2]: o = MyClass()

In [3]: o.get_cc()
Out[3]: (124, 124, 124)

In [4]: o.change_color()

In [5]: o.get_cc()
Out[5]: (65, 76, 436)
```